# Error: this declaration has no storage or type specifier

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am getting this message with everything that has `Node*` (this declaration has no storage or type specifier). Could somebody help and please send me in the right direction?

```
template <typename type>
Node* Stack<type>::pop() {
Node* retNode; // the node to be return
if(tos == NULL) {
    cerr << "*** Stack empty ***";
    exit(1);
}
else {
    retNode = tos; // store the location of tos
    tos = tos->getLink(); // move to new tos
    retNode->setLink(); // unlink the popped node from the stack
    size -= 1;
}
return retNode;
}
```

I am sure it's dealing with `Node*` but I just can't figure out what.

Below are my declarations for the node class that are being used in my stack class. Let me know if you need my declarations for the stack class as well because I just cant see the problem.

```
template <typename type>
class Node<type>{

private:
type data;
Node *link;

public:
Node(type p_item, Node *p_link);
type getData() const;
Node* getLink() const;
void setData(type p_data);
void setLink(Node *node);
};
```

Comment: You must have a declaration of `Node` in scope before this code will compile.  So, where is it?

Comment: Sorry, I have been fighting trying to understand this website's method of placing code in the comment section and I continue to have trouble with it.

Comment: Don't post that code in the comments, just edit your original post.

Comment: Thank you so much. I failed to realize that and assumed people wanted us to comment under it.

Comment: Clearly, `Node` is a template, so you need to use `Node<type> *` instead of `Node *` (assuming the `type` to be used is the same as you use with the `Stack` template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` is a class template, so you cannot use `Node` or `Node *` as data types. You must add template arguments in angle brackets, e.g. `Node<int>` or `Node<char> *` etc.

In the specific example you gave, it seems the following would be appropriate:

```
template <typename type>
Node<type>* Stack<type>::pop() {
  Node<type>* retNode;
  /* ... */
  return retNode;
}
```

I.e. the same type argument that is used for `Stack` should (probably) be used for `Node` as well.

Two further notes:

1. It seems odd that, while the `Node` template appears to implement internal data structures of your stack, `Node<type> *` pointers are returned by the pop function of the stack. It would seem more natural (and better encapsulation, and more intuitive for the users of your stack) to return `type` objects.
2. It also seems odd that the pop function calls `exit` (and thus brings the entire process to a halt) when the stack is empty. Perhaps returning `nullptr`, or a dummy object, or throwing an exception (or a similar strategy) would be more appropriate.

Comment: It seems to be working and the errors are gone. Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it !